# How to get information from xml after login with requests python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to get some data from an xml of a website which requires to login first. I try to get python requests Session and I am able to login using get method (shows 200). After that I try to get access to the xml, but it gets me 401.

So far I know that the server checks with each call whether the client is sending a JSESSIONID cookie and whether the VALUE matches the current session.

I manage to get the corresponding cookies and tried to send it via post method but still get 401.

Maybe I think to complicated. I also do not need to achieve this with requests. I would be glad to just get the information from the xml.

```
import requests

login_url = 'https://www.example.com/login

USER_NAME = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'pass'

xml = 'https://www.example.com/channel_index?123&p=web'   

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.get(login_url,auth = (USER_NAME, PASSWORD))
    print(response)   

    r = s.get(xml)    
    cookies = s.cookies.get_dict() 
    r = s.post(xml, cookies = cookies)
    print(r)
```

Comment: This question will be difficult for us to answer if we don't know more about the website. You're clearly getting an `Unauthorized` response, which means you're not authentication your requests correctly, but unless there is documentation or sample code we can run we probably can't help you out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.